# Conversion of character set in C#

Tags: c#, unicode

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I remove diacritics (accents) from a string in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/249087/how-do-i-remove-diacritics-accents-from-a-string-in-net)

Our project generates an string(Mērā nāma nitina hai) in web page and when we read it using Regex.match function then we get a string in which these special character are converted into some browser code like \&#\257(without backslash) in place of ā . So we want to convert it into 'a' or 'ā'. So that we can use it in further program.
Thanks

Comment: Please explain: do you want a regex to convert those special character to Latin equivalent?

Comment: @djechelon yeah, we want to convert it into 8-bit character set.

Comment: @Hosam Actually when we read string from web page using regex.match function then it read those special character as \&#\257 in place of 'ā'. And i want to solution of it.

Comment: @All: I don't see that this is a duplicate of the linked question. He doesn't want to get rid of the diacritics - he wants to convert the HTML entities into UTF-8.

Comment: @All: John Saunders is right, I just wanna convert Html character entities to simple character set. Then why this post has closed...? :(

Comment: OK, your wording is clearer now, so I'm nominating it to be reopened. But you should work on your language, because that was not what many people understood from the initial question.

Comment: @Hosam Really Sorry about that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im not sure that my method is absolutely right but it works for me:

**[EDIT]**

```
string first = @"M&#275;r&#257; n&#257;ma nitina hai";
first = System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(first);

byte[] ansi = System.Text.Encoding.Convert(Encoding.Unicode, Encoding.GetEncoding(1252), Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(first));
string output = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(System.Text.Encoding.Convert(Encoding.GetEncoding(1252), Encoding.Unicode, ansi));
MessageBox.Show(output);
```

The main idea of this code - you are converting your string to ANSI and back to UNICODE. After this action all diacritics is gone away.

Comment: @anton Actually we are not getting this string after regex.match function. we are getting "M\&#\275;r\&#\257; n\&#\257;ma nitina hai"(without \ ). and we want to convert it into original one.

Comment: @Sushant Jain: OK, Ive edit my answer

Comment: That's not a correct way to remove diacritics.

Comment: @František Žiačik: Yes, I know. This is workaround way. But I dont know how to do this right. May be you can give me a right direction for solution. The question OP has asked is aslo interesting for me.

Comment: @Anton Semenov: As Paolo Tedesco suggested in his answer, with the help of `Normalize`. See, for example, http://blogs.msdn.com/b/michkap/archive/2005/02/19/376617.aspx

Comment: But I think that's not what was asked here, it's all about the `HtmlDecode`.

Comment: I think you should merge this code with `String.Normalize` as clarified in the question's possible duplicate (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/249087/how-do-i-remove-diacritics-accents-from-a-string-in-net).

Comment: @Hosam Aly: Actually I should replace my code with code from your link :)

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
var correctStr = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(@"M&#275;r&#257; n&#257;ma nitina hai");
```

Explanation: `&#257;` is an [html entity character](http://www.w3schools.com/HTML/html_entities.asp) representing the special accented char with unicode code 257.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the [String.Normalize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ebza6ck1.aspx) method.